# Is there a way to copy a picture to clipboard using bash without using xclip?

Tags: bash, screenshot, copying, pasting

Hey I wanted to write my own little tool to take screenshots on Arch-Linux in Bash because I couldn't find one that supported area screenshots. 
I want to have the ability to copy the picture to clipboard so I can paste it into Libre-Office or WhatsApp.

I have tried xclip to make it work, but it just pasted out gibberish. So I need another approach. I've already seen some python code which supposedly solves the issue but this is my first bash script and didn't want to give up so easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dirname=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
if [ ! -d "/home/asdfasdf/Screenshot/$dirname" ]
then
    mkdir /home/asdfasdf/Screenshot/$dirname
fi

count=$(ls -1q /home/asdfasdf/Screenshot/$dirname | wc -l)
fd="/home/asdfasdf/Screenshot/$dirname/scr$count.png"

import $fd

# missing copy to clipboard -> xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i example.png didn't work for me
```

This is my first bash script so don't be too harsh (Improvements?). If there is no other way, how would I be going about this using python?

Cheers!

Hugenotte

Comment: bash doesn't even have a concept of a "clipboard" at all -- `xclip` is a completely separate piece of software unrelated to the shell itself. You could of course have or write a *different* piece of software that performs the same function -- but no, nothing built into bash supports any kind of system clipboard manipulation.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- you've got some missing quotes, and are running afoul of [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you want to count files in a directory without using `ls`, see [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! I guess I will have to try it in python then.

Comment: BTW, consider running `mkdir -p "/home/asdfasdf/Screenshot/$dirname"` unconditionally; it'll just be a silent noop in any circumstance where the `test -d` would have otherwise directed `mkdir` to be run.